# Why is the NavigationStack not navigating?

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation, coordinator-pattern

I am trying to hide the Navigation path of the NavigationStack into the ViewModel of a view but doing so breaks the NavigationStack, the stack adds the items correctly but it does not updates the UI.

This code shows a simple view with a button that is supposed to navigate to a new view and show the number of elements in the navigation stack.

Is there a way of making it work?

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestingCoordinatorNavigationApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView()
        }
    }
}

enum Destination {
    case firstPage
}

class Coordinator: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path: [ViewModel] = [] { didSet { debugPrint(path) } }
    
    func goToFirst() {
        path.append(ViewModel(number: 1, coordinator: self))
    }
}

class NavigationViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var coordinator = Coordinator()
}

struct NavigationView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = NavigationViewModel()
    // it workd fine if I do this:
    // @ObservedObject var coordinator = Coordinator()
    // and replace the call in the Button for coordinator.goToFirst()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $viewModel.coordinator.path) {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    viewModel.coordinator.goToFirst()
                }) {
                    Text("Go to first view")
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: ViewModel.self) { viewModel in
                    ViewFactory(viewModel: viewModel)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ViewFactory: View {
    var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        switch viewModel.number {
        case 1:
            ChildView(viewModel: viewModel)
        default:
            Text("ViewModel not recognized")
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is a view \(viewModel.number) and there are \(viewModel.coordinator.path.count) views in the stack")
            
            Button {
                debugPrint("Push another view in the stack")
                viewModel.coordinator.goToFirst()
            } label: {
                Text("Push another view")
            }
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel {
    var number: Int
    @ObservedObject var coordinator: Coordinator
    
    init(number: Int, coordinator: Coordinator) {
        self.number = number
        self.coordinator = coordinator
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: ViewModel, rhs: ViewModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.number == rhs.number
    }
}

extension ViewModel: Hashable {
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
         hasher.combine(ObjectIdentifier(self))
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it looks a bit redundant but this is an oversimplification of me trying to abstract the navigation from the view. I would like to be able to generate any view with a coordinator only by adding the viewModel to the navigation stack

Comment: First of all it is bad practice to name your types (NavigationView) similarly as SwiftUI types (SwiftUI.NavigationView  is still there), it might confuse compiler and you cannot be sure which one be used.

Comment: At second, you found the issue yourself - your custom `NavigationView` does not observe published path (it observes viewModel, but viewmodel.coordinator is not changed), if view observes path (via Coordinator directly) it works. It is due to misunderstanding of how ObservedObject works - find and look Apple's WWDC session about that.